# Urn Problem - Number of Permutations

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I have a quick question and would be very gladful for any help.

We view an Urn Problem, where we put back the balls after each drawing.
Let  $n \in \mathbb{N}$ be the number of balls in the urn and view the case where $k \in \mathbb{N}$ balls are drawn.

So for instance, we can view $(b_1,...,b_k)$ as a sequence of $k$ drawings, where $b_i$ represent a ball.

So let the sequence of $k$ drawings result in drawings of $m_1$ times the ball $a_1$, $m_2$ times the ball $a_2$, ..., $m_l$ times the ball $a_l$, where $\sum_{i=1}^l m_i=k$, and where $a_i$ are distinct, which means $a_s \neq a_t$ for all $s\neq t$ with $s,t \in [1,...,l]$.

My question is: What is the number of **different** sequences of length $k$ which result in the above drawings?

Comment: In what sense is your question quick? If $(a_1,\dots,a_k)$ denotes a sequence of $k$ drawings then the $a_i$ are not necessarily distinct. You should work with a set $\{a_1,\dots,a_l\}$ having $l$ elements. Then $\sum_{i=1}^lm_i=k$ makes sense.

Comment: Hmm you are right, I should not have called the sequence in paragraph 3 as $a_i$, I will change it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are the [multinomial coefficient](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients)

$$\binom{k}{m_1,m_2,\ldots,m_\ell}=\frac{k!}{m_1!m_2!\ldots m_\ell!}$$

ways to choose $m_1$ positions in the sequence for the draws of ball $a_1$, $m_2$ positions for the draws of ball $a_2$, and so on. Each of these possible choices uniquely determines one of the possible sequences.

Comment: This answers the question for *fixed* balls $a_1,\dots,a_l$, wich is indeed the question of the OP. To avoid confusion I would not speak of "$a_1$ balls" but of "ball $a_1$".

Comment: @mango: You're welcome!

Comment: @drhab: Thanks.